# Install Drupal in a subfolder of an existing website

Tags: installation

I have a question about drupal installation in a subfolder: We have an existing website running on Magento. Now for some special functionalities we need to build some drupal pages, which all should be in a subfolder.
Example.
Main URL is (Magento): www.mysite.com
Drupal installation: www.mysite.com/specialpages
all other pages are still Magento as today, e.g. www.mysite.com/page1, www.mysite.com/folder1/page12 etc.

Is it possible to install drupal in this subfolder?

thanks for any help / information

Answer (score 1):

Drupal and Magento both use .htaccess rules for functionality.   One slight quirk with Apache is that .htaccess is processed from a directory up through all of the parents.  This means that if your Drupal install is inside your Magento install, Magento's .htaccess *may* interfere with Drupal (a Magento directive may be applied after a Drupal one).  This is going to totally depend on your setup.  At very least, you will likely need to set `RewriteBase` in the Drupal .htaccess for things to work properly.  I have seen similar situations work perfecty fine, but others fail in bizarre ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not, you can install drupal in a sub-folder and provide drupal pages link in your magento website. That should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give a short feedback:
We have installed drupal in the subfolder and all is working well.
There was just one problem: relative links in css files of the theme did not work relative to the drupal installation but relative to the main installation.So we had do adjust these paths (setting baseurl etc. did not work). relative links in modules worked well.